# How do I make a Seamless Run Cycle?

Tags: animation, fcurves

I have a character using a rig from Mixamo (but not a Mixamo motion). I'm trying to set up a run cycle. The first and last frames are in the same pose when the character's foot makes contact with the ground. Between these frames, things look/move well.

But, when the animation reaches the last frame and loops to the first there is a slight lag.

I'm working in Global orientation mode, and most of the joint rotations are happening on the X-axis (Eular rotation). In the graph editor, I make sure that the curves on the first and last frame are adjusted to be as close to seamless (no leveling off at the bottom of the curve).

My biggest challenge is the arms. Even with these adjustments, one arm (coming from the back) looks like it's trying to shove up somewhere, while the other arm looks like it's trying to pull something hard.

At certain speeds, this weirdness is hidden. I'm hoping to slo-mo the shot as well, but then the weirdness is obvious. What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Try duplicating the first frame and dragging the duplicate to one frame **after** the last frame on the timeline and see if that cures the jumping.

Comment: if John's solution doesn't work please share the file (the armature only): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, @John Eason. Since the first and last frames are already the same, wouldn't that cause 3 similar frames at that point?

Comment: as John wrote, you get a seamless loop, if you duplicate the first keyframe after (!) the render end (last frame). Think of animating a circle via angle. If you keyframe from 0 to 360, you will have 2 keyframes which are the same (keyframe 0 and 360). If you render now just from frame 0 to 359, it will be seamlsess.

Comment: @BrianG If the first and last keyframes are already identical, just move the last keyframe one frame to the right as Chris says rather than duplicating the first one.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for clarifying, I get it now.

Comment: @JohnEason, thank you!